# importing csv into jupyter with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, import

```py
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\omananyi.yakubu\Desktop\pandas_test\RE07.01_OperatorActionsDetailed.csv")data.head()
```

I tried importing a CSV file but it came out with "invalid syntax".
Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data` from syntax:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\omananyi.yakubu\Desktop\pandas_test\RE07.01_OperatorActionsDetailed.csv").head()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 

# Read data from file 'RE07.01_OperatorActionsDetailed.csv'    
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\omananyi.yakubu\Desktop\pandas_test\RE07.01_OperatorActionsDetailed.csv") 

#Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
data.head()
```